# Using Arrays to calc. accuracy

Tags: java, arrays

This is a memory experiment that flashes up to 3 numbers on the screen, then disappears for a couple seconds then asks the user to replay the number/s. I am trying to use an array to calculate the accuracy of the user's answer.  So I was trying to use a 2d array with the random generator method in order to tell what number is where. It might be pretty inefficient, but I'm trying my best. Here is what I have so far...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pitt3 
{
    static int pause = 4;
    static int Screen_Size = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //USED TO CALC. USER'S ACCURACY
        int accuracy = 99;

        for (int x = 0; x<2; x++)
        {
            //CREATES ARRAYS TO GENERATE DIGITS
            int[] array1 = new int[generateDigits(1)];
            int[] array2 = new int[generateDigits(1)];
            int[] array3 = new int[generateDigits(1)];


            //PRINTS OUT #'S + PAUSES
            System.out.println("Here are your numbers: ");
            System.out.println(generateDigits(1));
            System.out.println(generateDigits(1));
            System.out.println(generateDigits(1)); pause(4);


            //SPACES OUT THE QUESTION FROM ANSWER
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + 
            "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + 
            "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

            //PRINTS OUT #'S + PAUSES
            System.out.println("What is the first number? ");
            int ANSWER1a = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("What is the second number? ");
            int ANSWER1b = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("What is the third number? ");
            int ANSWER1c = keyboard.nextInt();


            if (ANSWER1a != array1[0] || ANSWER1b != array2[0] || ANSWER1c != array3[0])
            {
                accuracy = (accuracy - 33);
            }

            if (ANSWER1a == array1[0] || ANSWER1b == array2[0] || ANSWER1c == array3[0])
            {
                accuracy = accuracy;
            }

            System.out.println("Your accuracy was " + accuracy + "%");


        }

    }




    /**
     *GENERATES A RANDOM #
     */
    public static int generateDigits(int maxDigits)
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int numberDigits = generator.nextInt(maxDigits) + 1;
        int result = 0;

        for(int n = 0; n < numberDigits; n++)
        {
            result = result + generator.nextInt(10);
        }

        return result;

    }

    /**
     *SETS COMP. TO SLEEP FOR SPECIFIED SECONDS
     */
    public static int pause (int seconds)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e){}
        return pause;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What does "accuracy" mean? Please provide an example that shows how you calculate this. Also, do you have a question?

Comment: "pretty inefficient" I suggest you make sure small portions of the code compiles before writing more code, or you are likely to end up with a mess.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your question is, but I would check this code using a debugger to understand what your code really does because there is a lot of code which is not doing what you think it is doing.

A common mistake with beginners is to write too much code without testing it or in some cases even checking it compiles.  This results in a massive mess which is very difficult to fix.

I suggest starting again with a small section of code which compiles.  Use methods to break up your code and test it works as you go.

For example,

```
String[] array = new String[generateDigits(3)];
```

This creates a random length array of `null` values

---

I don't see how this even compiles, but if it did I doubt it would do what you wanted.

```
array[0][0] = ANSWER2a;
array[0][1] = ANSWER2b;
array[0][2] = ANSWER2c;

if (ANSWER2a == generateDigits[0][0])
{

}

if (ANSWER2a != generateDigits[0][0])
{
    accuracy = accuracy - 50;
}
```

---

This can print both of these lines for the same answer.

```
if (ANSWER1 == generateDigits(3))
{
    System.out.println("You were 100% accurate");
}

if (ANSWER1 != generateDigits(3))
{
    System.out.println("You were 0% accurate");
}
```

---

This will generate a number between 0 and 27 which is not what you had in mind.

```
for(int n = 0; n < numberDigits; n++)
{
    result = result + generator.nextInt(10);
}
```

---

This method doesn't appear to be useful. I would delete it

```
public static void pause (int seconds)
```

You need to think about what your code is really doing.

Comment: I need the pause method in order to give the user time to view the numbers. I updated the code with a much simpler version which I think is much better. Lmk how it looks.

Comment: I see they have 4 seconds to memorise the number. It's just a shame the program doesn't remember it so it has no way of checking you were right ;) (hint , hint)

Comment: I suggest you read the comment about the first line I mention.  You haven't fixed that problem yet.

Comment: It does pause, it just doesn't calc. the correct accuracy though. Are you saying that is because of the pause error? I also just updated the code to a little different approach.

Comment: It does calculate the correct accuracy because you don't save the random numbers you generated. Instead you compare the number against new random numbers.  It's like being asked to predict what then next three numbers will be.  Again, this should be obvious if you used your debugger correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your program right, you want it to do is:

1. Output a set of numbers.
2. Hide the numbers and then pause for 4 seconds.
3. User inputs all the numbers he can remember.
4. Program calculates how accurate he/she was.

I suggest you make the program in stages, do it for one number first. Then do it for several numbers. Then upgrade it to arrays. Then add the calculation for accuracy. You are mixing Arrays, Strings and Ints in a real jumble.

Tip: have one array for randomNumbers[] and one for userAnswers[], have a loop compare them.

```
        //PRINTS OUT #'S + PAUSES
        System.out.println("Here are your numbers: ");
        System.out.println(generateDigits(1));
        System.out.println(generateDigits(1));
        System.out.println(generateDigits(1)); pause(4);
```

This part output a new set of random numbers unrelated to array1, array2 and array3 as I see it.